# VS2010 UML code generation - is it possible?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, uml

I have created a complex UML class diagram in my VS2010 IDE.
I am struggling how to generate the C++ (native) code from it.

Anyone knows how to do this?

This looks like a very straightforward simple task, but for some reason i can't find how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to do that with [VS Feature packs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff657795.aspx) and [T4 templates](http://www.olegsych.com/2010/01/uml-modeling-and-code-generation-in-visual-studio-2010/)

Comment: does the VF Feature pack license is separately paid? or i can simply download it and install it...

Comment: Requires MSDN subscribers license. If you don't have that, alternative is to look for [third party tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unified_Modeling_Language_tools) that let you generate code from UML diagrams.

Comment: There's more info about generating code from a UML class diagram here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff657795.aspx